# jqgrid xml generating empty cell

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using this code to generate xml from my jqgrid's data:

```
var grid =  $("#gridTable");
var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getRowData');
var xml_string = '<rows>\n' + xmlJsonClass.json2xml ({rowTest:dataFromGrid}, '\t') +
                 '</rows>';
```

when the cell inside the grid is empty i get inside the xml tag "_EMPTY_STRING" , 
how can i change it to be just empty xml tag (like this: `<cell1></cell1>`) 
while generating it ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way to do this is just to append your code with the following line

```
xml_string = xml_string.replace(/>__EMPTY_STRING_<\//g, "><\/");
```

It will cut all `__EMPTY_STRING_` strings.