# jqgrid get values from combobox inside cell

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using select type inside a column , when I'm generating the xml from the grid's data , i can't get the value of the select type cell.

This is my code:

```
{name:'code',index:'code', width:80, sorttype:"int" , editable:true,edittype:"select",
                                         editoptions:
                                         {
                                           value:"1:11 ;2:22" }
```

and the xml generating is with:

```
var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getRowData');
  var xml = xmlJsonClass.json2xml ({Row: dataFromGrid}, '\t');
```

I get inside the xml "11" intead of "1".

How can i get the option value?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: Which `datatype` has the jqGrid?

Comment: @Oleg: data type "xmlstring".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `datatype:"xmlstring"` it will be changed to the "local" datatype after the filling of the grid. So like in case of the `datatype:"local"` the grid has internal `data` parameter which represent grid data and not the visualization of the current page of data which you receive with

```
var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getRowData');
```

So I recommend you to use

```
var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'data');
```

to get the data from the grid.

Comment: @Oleg: thank's! I think it works , but now i get inside my xml <_id_> tag - and i don't want it inside my xml , is there a way not to generate it?

Comment: @Oleg: I have a nother problem, i have a function that checks all values of the cells inside the grid: var grid =get_proportional_grid();var ids = grid.getDataIDs();for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
{var rowData=grid.getRowData(ids[i]);alert(rowData.code)} - and the value i get is "11" and not the option value itself - which is 1.. Any idea?

Comment: @Oleg: sorry for all the questions , but i think i'm in the wrong direction..so before you answer my last comments - I want to have a "select" inisde the cells of a column, it will be initialized according to the values i get from the xmlstring (but will have permanent values - and will show the value taht was accepted in the xmlstring). I want to see this the option of the value, but when i approch the cell i want always to get it's value and not the option. should i use formatter and unformatter for this? I can't find any example for this..appritiate your help.

Comment: @user590586: Probably you have the problem because you don't use [formatter:'select'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select). If you add it you should place in the column the values "1" or "2" (place in the xml string which you use as the input) which will be hold in `data` "1" or "2", but which will be displayed as "11" and "22" correspond to the `value` from the `editoptions`. Is it what you want?

Comment: @Oleg: thank's!! I tried  formatter:'select' and this is what exactly i ment! so thank's!! the only problemi still have is from my first comment , about grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'data'), generating the "<_id_>" tag - which i don't want to create..

Comment: @user590586: You can't change this behavior in the current version of jqGrid. So the solution I see very easy. You should use `xml = xml .replace(/<_id_>/g, "<id>");` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914337/jqgrid-xml-generating-empty-cell/4914503#4914503).

Comment: @Oleg:o.k.. but now after i tried all my functions , when I'm using var dataFromGrid = grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'data') ,i have an error , I changed it back to grid.jqGrid ('getRowData') , and now it works good..

Comment: @user590586: When you write "after i tried all my functions ... i have an error" it gives almost no information. Mush better to include the code which has problem. In any debugger (IE developer tools for example) you can see exactly **where** you have an error and which error. So either you yourself can fix the error or other (if you posted the code). Do you want to solve the problem?

Comment: @Oleg: It works good as it is now , do you think I should use grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'data') , even if grid.jqGrid ('getRowData') works for me?

Comment: @user590586: It's depend on many things. If you use local paging for example you have to use `grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data')`. In general `grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data')` return reference to the object with all data of the grid: so return exactly what you need. The `grid.jqGrid ('getRowData');` on the other side read the grid contain from the **displayed page** and call *unformatter* to get the data. The first returns immediately the second can take some time. The most unclear for me is why you have errors using `grid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'data')` because the way should also work.

Comment: @Oleg: I will test it later again and send you the error i get.. thank's!

Comment: @Oleg: I've tested the grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data'),and i get this error only when i generate the xml (after i added anew row to the grid , if not adding a row it works without an error): " 'undefined' is null or not an object  jquery.jqGrid.min.js, line 420 character 287" and the marked line in the debugger: "i+=typeof d==="function"?j+"<"+c+"><![CDATA["+d+"]]\></"+c+">":d.toString()==='""'||d.toString().length===0?j+"<"+c+">__EMPTY_STRING_</"+c+">":j+"<"+c+">"+d.toString()+"</"+c+">" " . any help will be appritiated!

Comment: @user590586: I can help you only if you posted enough information **to be able to reproduce** your problem. Currently it looks like you have the problem in the code how you add the row or which columns in the grid you mot mark as editable. If you debug the code you should use **developer version** of jqGrid (from src subdirectory of the jqGrid download). See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install#development_installation) for more information.

Comment: @Oleg: I decided for now to put this a side and deal with it after i'll solve other problems i have. so i appritiate your help, thank'ssss!!

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this in local processing mode:

```
var rows = jQuery(this).getRowData();
var cols = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
for (var col in cols) {
     if (cols[col].edittype == 'select') {
         var VALs = cols[col].editoptions.value;
         if (typeof (VALs) == "object") {
             for (var row in rows) {
                 for (var v in VALs) {
                     if (rows[row][cols[col].name] == VALs[v]) {
                           rows[row][cols[col].name] = v;
                                break;
                      }
                  }
              }
           }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only need the selected ID in the data, you can specify `formatter: 'select'`

```
...
{
  name: 'unit', index: 'unit', editable: true, formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { value: "1:11 ; 2:22" }
},
...
```

then retriving the grid data :

```
var griddata = $('#gridID').getGridParam('data');
alert(JSON.stringify(griddata));
```